# Force a line break inside the button's text when using small screens

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, responsive-design

I have a responsive web app that contains some buttons which are too large for small mobile screens. They have too much text in them so they end up going off the screen.
I am currently using the `a` tag as a button by given them bootstrap classes. So the code currently looks like this:

```
<a className='btn btn-default'>Here I have a button with long text in it, which causes some text to go off screen when in small mobile devices.</a>
```

I would like add a line break to the text, so that way it won't go off the screen (which is why I don't simply add a `<br/>`), but only on the small screens. How could I do that?

Edit: Here is a fuller view of the code:

```
<div className='row'>
  <div className='col-sm-12'>
    <p>Some text which is irrelevant to the problem.</p>
    <a className='btn btn-default'>Here I have a button with long text in it, which causes some text to go off screen when in small mobile devices.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need the code of your parent element.

Comment: @HorsSujet I have updated the OP with the div it belongs to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Bootstrap uses `white-space: nowrap` for its buttons, but you can override that for smaller screens:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 30em) {
  body .btn { white-space: normal }
}
```

2) If you want more control over the wrapping, you can add spans around the lines you want, and then set `display: block` on smaller screens:

```
<a className='btn btn-default'>
  <span>This will be line 1</span>
  <span> followed by line 2</span>
</a>

@media only screen and (max-width: 30em) {
  .btn span { display: block }
}
```

> Note: `30em` is equal to 480px on most devices. You should always define media queries in `em`. The conversion is easy: divide your pixel number by 16. This will allow your site to render correctly for users who have adjusted their default browser font size for easier reading.

Comment: Number 1 was the solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the responsive utilities that Bootstrap offers:

**Bootstrap 3:**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities

You can use something like:

`<br class="hidden-md hidden-lg">`

**Bootstrap 4:**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

You can use something like:

`<br class="d-md-none">`

Adjust the breakpoint depending on what screen sizes you want to target.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it worked for me

```
input[type="submit"] {
   white-space: normal;
}
```

Also we have to set -webkit-appearance as none to remove specific styling of the input.