# Wordwrap on Bootstrap button does not work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have a bootstrap layout on a simple page, just rows with some columns ordered on fullscreen, no with or hight is set and that should remain that way.

here is my layout definition

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="section col-lg">
            <ul class="list-group>
```

inside the ul i have a button like this

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-success list-group-item list-group-item-warning"
    href="https://www.google.at" target="_blank">
    <i class="material-icons">extension</i>
    <br>
    asdfasdfasdfasd fasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
</a>
```

but now the problem is that the button text overflows and does not wrap inside the button.

[image]

i already tried the solution from [Force a line break inside the button's text when using small screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767226/force-a-line-break-inside-the-buttons-text-when-using-small-screens) but this also did nothing but cut the button text and not wraping it into the next line

i also tried with `overflow : hidden;` but this also just hides the text before it overflows

Comment: can you please share your css also for more understating?

Comment: my css does not contain anything atm. i load everything from bootstrap.

Comment: I have used your same code and repeat your col-lg five times. it works perfectly. show the SS here: https://prnt.sc/pab8k3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force a line break inside the button's text when using small screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767226/force-a-line-break-inside-the-buttons-text-when-using-small-screens)

Comment: Bootstrap: "list-group-item list-group-item-warning" what are these classes for does they contain colour properties alone or anything else?

Comment: @vssadineni sorry i oversaw a line in my code. the button is inside a `<ul>` tag and which is from class `list-group` and the `list-group-item` is just the class for it `list-group-item-warning` should only have coloring properties in it

Comment: I doubt if it has some white-space: nowrap; property. I think .btn class has  white-space: nowrap; property in it if you could add  white-space: initial; & add some width to it.I think it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding this @media query CSS for smaller screens you can make the button text split on gaps in the button sentence as many times as required to fit inside the button:

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 30em) {

   body .btn { white-space: normal; }

}
```

As you can see in this image, this will cover all viewing devices down to a width of 232px, which is well below the standard width for coding the smallest media queries:

[image]

Even if you wanted to code below this standard width the CSS snippet still works. Here is the result at an almost ridiculous width of 186px, achieved simply by splitting the text in your question once more. You can make the text even smaller by adding Bootstrap's recommended usage of `<small></small>` on BS4 `.btn` text >>> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#inline-text-elements

[image]

I've also added the CSS in a Stack Overflow code snippet below as evidence of it's functional viability, though I should note (as you already know) that it's not my own code. I got it from another Stack Overflow question here >>> [Force a line break inside the button's text when using small screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767226/force-a-line-break-inside-the-buttons-text-when-using-small-screens)

I hope that it helps to resolve your issues.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 30em) {
  body .btn { white-space: normal; }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <style>


    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
   <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="section col-lg">
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-success list-group-item list-group-item-warning"
     href="https://www.google.at" target="_blank">
     <i class="material-icons">extension</i>
     <br>
     asdfasdfasdfasd fasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>


 
 <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes i already undersood the functionality of `@media` but it somehow does not work with my code it still overflows even though i have the query in my css it does not appeal to my html somehow

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you didn't understand _ With this answer we have simply established that the recommended CSS does indeed work_ simply not on your page _ Perhaps it would be a good idea to post all of the code on the "simple page" site_ so that we can try to establish what differences there might be _ They might not be in your actual code but rather in the version of Bootstrap or jQuery or some other cause _ If you're willing to take the time to post all of the code then I'll be happy to test it locally

Comment: this solution worked perfectly. seems that it was a problem related to InternetExplorer10. in Chrome and Firefox it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the p tag:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-success list-group-item list-group-item-warning"
    href="https://www.google.at" target="_blank">
    <i class="material-icons">extension</i>
    <br>
    <p>asdfasdfasdfasd fasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
</a>
```

Comment: <p> didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try to use class = "d-inline-block text-truncate" in a tag

Comment: also no change.

Comment: if i change it on the button itself it works, but it cuts it of, i want it to go into the next line so i still can see the whole text. this solution also was achieved by me with `overflow: hidden;` in a class